# Removing an Entity completely from Jhipster built Application

Tags: node.js, jhipster

I have a requirement to accompish, which is to delete an entity completely, which has been created using jhipster.
If I use the command "jhipster entity entityName", it gives option to delete fields and relationships only but not complete removal of entity. While doing some research, I came across this link [https://github.com/jhipster/generator-jhipster/pull/4369][1]. But there seems to be no solution to it.
Also if I'm using the above command to remove the fields and relationships with the help of the existing entityName.json file in .jhipster folder to avoid the prompts on cmd, I need to keep the fields and relationships keys in that json file as null or [], right?

Looking for some help on this.Thanks.

Comment: No solution offered by JHipster, people usually rely on git with a commit per entity creation so that they can easily rollback.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification @GaëlMarziou.